# Tel Aviv safety, cost of living, etc

Tags: indian-citizens, safety, israel

I am an Indian citizen. I am going to travel to Tel Aviv for long term. So my company is going to apply for a work permit.

1. Is it safe to live long-term in Tel Aviv and would it be safe to bring my family after 1 year?
2. What is the salary range for a senior technical consultant in the banking industry?
3. Please share the cost of living for a bachelor.
4. Any racism in Tel Aviv?
5. Any terrorism in Tel Aviv?
6. Would it be possible to apply for a job in Saudi Arabia or any Arab countries after a long stay in Israel?

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time. Asking a question like "is it safe to live in Tel Aviv" is fine, but including five more questions such as "what is the salary for this super-specific but not at all well-specified job?" can only serve to confuse people, when the headline question is so simple.

Comment: You have too many questions for one post, you really need to split many (most) of those out into separate questions. See the help section for more on how this site does (and doesn't!) work!

Comment: So you made the decision to complicate the extremely simple (and good) title, but leave all the other questions in? Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Tel Aviv and Israel is relatively safe for families, as in any other place in the world there are places you don't want to go.
Please define Senior Technical Consultant to get a better estimation, you can use search for "סקר שכר" (salary survey in Hebrew) and use Google/Bing translate to read it.
Cost of living can widely vary, Tel Aviv itself is very expensive but costs drops significantly if you live further away. Again you will need to add more information here about your needs and expectations.
There is some racism in Tel Aviv, but since Israel is a multi cultural nation I don't think it is something to worry about.
Read the papers about terrorism- it happens, but again it is usually not something the average person worries about too much.
I can't answer #6, but I suppose the answerd would be no.